# charts.PerformanceSummary: how to set sequential colors

Tags: r

```
require(quantmod)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)

getSymbols(c('SP500', 'WAAA', 'WBAA'), src = 'FRED', from = '1950-01-01')
X <- na.omit(merge(to.weekly(SP500), WAAA, WBAA))

dWAAA <- diff(WAAA / 100, 1)
dWBAA <- diff(WBAA / 100, 1)

D <- 20

dP.WAAA <- - D * dWAAA
dP.WBAA <- - D * dWBAA

charts.PerformanceSummary(p = .99, R = dP.WAAA['1990-01-01/2012-08-17'],
                          methods = 'ModifiedES', width = 48)
charts.PerformanceSummary(p = .99, R = dP.WBAA['1990-01-01/2012-08-17'],
                          methods = 'ModifiedES', width = 48)
```

May you tell me any way to set colors' smoothing-transitions-sequential palette in order to replace default black color with something which looks nicer?

I would like something which is blue-based and changes blue variety starting from the 1st plot ending to the 3rd one.

Thanks,

Comment: This [post about colour wheels](http://www.stubbornmule.net/2011/11/more-colour-wheels/) may (or may not) be of some help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See `?chart.TimeSeries`.  I believe that the options you want are likely:

```
element.color # for the boxes, axes, etc
# and
colorset # for the actual chart lines
# try
colorset = 'darkblue'
# or
colorset = 'lightblue'
# as an extra argument to charts.PerformanceSummary
```

The colorsets provide different colors for the different chart elements, and work best when you plot more than one series on the same chart, to compare an asset to an index or a peer group, for example.

A vertical color ramp in R is not possible using base graphics, and conveys no information anyway.